# Passport Node(Error: Failed to deserialize user out of session.)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Node.js, express, passport and MySQL.

Here is my deserialize code:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
connection.query("select * from users where UserId = "+id,function(err,rows){  
        console.log(rows); 
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});
```

Also, checked using console.log that "rows" is returning the row of the required user.

```
app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return the row

```
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return done(null,err);
    }
    done(null, rows[0]); // return row[0]
```

Comment: like so?     app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
       req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, rows[0]);
    });

Comment: Thank you. Was my mistake. I changed the DB and the table "users" was renamed as "user"...

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up comment: errors should be passed as the first argument for the `done()` function:

`return done(err, null);`

or

`return done(err);`

whereas deserialized objects should passed as you have it:

`return done(err, rows[0]);`